# How to determine if there are any event handlers for DataGridView.CellFormatting event?

Tags: c#, datagridview, event-handling

I'm writing a control which inherits from a DataGridView. One of the things I would like to do is to handle the bug whereby a column's format provider is not used without handling the CellFormatting event *(and doing the formatting myself)*.

I thought I would write an "OnCellFormatting" method which says *"if there's a column format provider, and there's no CellFormatting event handler(s), do the formatting"*.

The important bit (I thought) was *"...and there's no CellFormatting event handler"*.

Now, in the past when I've written controls with events, I've done something like this:

```
  public event EventHandler SomethingHappened;

  protected void OnSomethingHappened(EventArgs e)
  {
     EventHandler handler = this.SomethingHappened;
     if (handler != null) handler(this, e);
  }
```

This works fine and my understanding is that this pattern determines if handlers are attached to the event and, if so, invoke those handlers. Fair enough, but why can't I do this:

```
  protected void OnCellFormatting(EventArgs e)
  {
     EventHandler handler = this.CellFormatting;
     if (handler == null) DoSomething();
  }
```

The error is "The event 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.CellFormatting' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -="

What's different about this (type of) event ?

If I go to the definition of the event, and create my own, ie.

public event DataGridViewCellFormattingEventHandler CellFormatting2

...the compiler is quite happy to assign this to my "handler" variable, so my question is - what's different with the CellFormatting event *(and, one presumes, many others)* that I cannot determine if there are any event handlers for it ?

Thanks,
Ross

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the class that declares the event has full access to it.

For instance, you cannot invoke an event from other classes - even derived ones.

You are in this situation, because you are deriving from `DataGridView`.

---

You may be able to use reflection:

[How do I raise an event via reflection in .NET (c#)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198543/how-do-i-raise-an-event-via-reflection-in-net-c)

[MSDN: Type.GetEvent Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getevent(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Thanks. I did find this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-NZ/netfxbcl/thread/45071852-3a61-4181-9a25-068a8698b8b6 (which has a method to get a list of event handler delegates) which, while clever, is not the sort of thing I would want to put in production code.

Answer (score 0):

That shows the assignment can't be performed because it's read only. May be you can try declaring the handler private?

Comment: Thanks - although its not because anything is read-only, its because the inheriting control cannot access the events of the inherited control.