# How to raise a click event manually for a button in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-8

How to raise a click  event manually for a button in windows phone ?
Is it possible technically  ? And is that a good suggestion to raise such event manually ?

Answer (score 0):

You can raise events manually just like with any other function, since per-se, an event handler is nothing but a function that is associated with data passed to it in case of an event.

So, let's say you have a mock event handler:

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("TEST");
}
```

You can easily invoke it manually with:

```
Button_Click_1(btnTest, new RoutedEventArgs());
```

In this case, you can supply your own sender. If you want to raise an event specifically, without having to explicitly bind to your own event handler, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/586156/303696) - you can use Reflection, although I am not sure why you'd need it like that.

Comment: There's a difference between event and event handler, isn't it? Especially between routed event and event handler.

Comment: Event != event handler. You raise an event and handle it through an, obviously, event handler.

Comment: OP asked how to raise an event, not how to call a handler function. There is a huge difference between calling one single handler and invoking an event with potentially bug number of listeners. Especially in case of routed events like Click.