# Convert event from .net 1.1 to .net 2.0 or above

Tags: c#, .net, events

I decompiled a program built with .NET 1.1 and I need to rewrite in .NET 2.0 or above. I have difficulty understanding this code, and event is not my strong point. Visual Studio complains

"The event 'dataTransfering' can only appear on the hand side of += or -="

```
public delegate void DataTransferringDelegate(string name, long transBytes, long totalBytes);

public event DataTransferringDelegate dataTransferring
    {
        [MethodImpl(32)]
        add
        {
            this.dataTransferring = (FtpIO.DataTransferringDelegate)Delegate.Combine(this.dataTransferring, value);
        }
        [MethodImpl(32)]
        remove
        {
            this.dataTransferring = (FtpIO.DataTransferringDelegate)Delegate.Remove(this.dataTransferring, value);
        }
    }

public void upload(string fileName, bool resume)
{
    long length;
    long num2 = 0L;
    // some code removed here
    this.dataTransferring(fileName, num2, length);
}
```

So how to fix this code in .NET 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see is [how compiler implements Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16281189/how-are-events-implemented). You don't need those, compiler will create them automatically.

Revise your code and remove those details, like this:

```
public delegate void DataTransferringDelegate(string name, long transBytes, long totalBytes);

public event DataTransferringDelegate dataTransferring;

public void upload(string fileName, bool resume)
{
    long length;
    long num2 = 0L;
    // some code removed here
    dataTransferring(fileName, num2, length);
}
```