# Parameter in event handler is not hitting while debugging

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a event handler like this code below :

```
viewer.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing += new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.SubreportProcessingEventHandler(LocalReport_SubreportProcessing);
```

And this method as a parameter for event handler above :

```
private static void LocalReport_SubreportProcessing(object sender, SubreportProcessingEventArgs e) {

        DateTime movementDate = Convert.ToDateTime(e.Parameters[0].Values[0]);

        TourTransactionsController controller = new TourTransactionsController();

        var movement = controller.Movements();

        List<Movement> movementList = new List<Movement>();
        movementList.Add(new Movement {
            Destination = "TEST",
            MovementDescription = "TEST",
            DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime("2017-09-25")
        });

        e.DataSources.Clear();

        e.DataSources.Add(new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportDataSource() {
            Name = "DSMovements",
            Value = movementList
        });

        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Both of those method is written in a **WEB API Controller**. The event handler is hitting while debugging, but after I press <kbd>F11</kbd> (step into) while debugging the `LocalReport_SubreportProcessing` method is not hitting. Why is `LocalReport_SubreportProcessing` method not hitting ?

Any help or answer is really appreciated.

Comment: You only `+=` / `add` the event-handler. Are you sure the event is fired from `LocalReport` ?

Comment: I think because the code is executed when I hit the Web API, the event is fire from Web API. Is that possible to fired a event handler when hitting the web api ?

Comment: Sorry it's hard to understand what you want. `The eventhandler is hitting while debugging, but after I press F11 (step into)` - Do you expect that the event-handler is called when you `+=` / `add` it ?

Comment: Yes. I expect that the event handler is called when I += it. To be honest, I'm not sure that I understand how event handler works. Is my understanding that the event handler is called when I += / add it correct ?

Answer (score 0):

Event's are not called when you register / `add` `+=` them.

Events are called when the owning class invokes it.

```
public class EventTest
{
    void SomeOperation()
    {
        //Do something
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        SomeOperation();
        RunFinished?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty); //Invoke the event, indicating that something has happened or finished
    }

    //The event itself
    public event EventHandler RunFinished;
}

public class EventSubscriber
{
    EventTest _ET = new EventTest();

    public EventSubscriber()
    {
        _ET.RunFinished += ETRunFinished; //Register my method, called when the event occurs (is invoked)
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        _ET.Run();
        Console.WriteLine("Something completed.");
    }

    void ETRunFinished(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("My event handler was executed.");
    }
}
```

Your handler will be called when the event fires.

When registering `+=` or `-=` unregistering (add / remove) they will NOT be invoked.

For a more [detailed tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx) please refer to MSDN.

Comment: Ah, I get it. But what I used as `EventHandler` in my code is `SubreportProcessingEventHandler` from `Microsoft.Reporting.Webforms`. I try to Invoke the `EventHandler` with `viewer.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing?.Invoke(LocalReport_SubreportProcessing)` but I got an error message `The event 'LocalReport.SubreportProcessing' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=` and `There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'e' of 'SubreportProcessingEventHandler.Invoke(object, SubreportProcessingEventArgs)'` Is there any other way to invoke the `EventHandler` ?

Comment: @SatriaJanaka You can only invoke an `event` within the declaring class. Deriving from it won't help you either. It is possible to [invoke it via reflection,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198543/how-do-i-raise-an-event-via-reflection-in-net-c) but that's surely not what you want here

Comment: @SatriaJanaka If you want to call/invoke a method, just do it. Register it on an event to receive a notification when the event occurs and you want to do something.